# How to autoremove linked Docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a container with PHP and a linked container with MySQL database, because I need an ability to run PHPUnit with database (integration tests).

The basic command looks like this:

```
docker run -i --rm --link db binarydata/phpunit php script.php
```

I have created `db` container and started it before running this command.

`binarydata/phpunit` container gets removed after a command was run. But `db` container stays up and running.

Question is: how can I achieve `--rm` functionality on a linked container, so it will be removed too after command was executed?

Comment: What are you using to launch the tests?

Comment: @Matt I am using PHPStorm and the above command is wrapped in a shell script to use that shell script as php interpreter, like it described here: http://obrown.io/2015/12/23/phpunit-docker-phpstorm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I achieve --rm functionality on a linked container, so it will be removed too after command was executed?

First, you don't have to use `--link` anymore with docker 1.10+. [docker-compose will create for you a network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in which all containers see each others.
And with [docker-compose `alias`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks), you can declare your `binary/phpunit` as "`db`" for other containers to use.

Second, with that network in place, if you stop/remove the php container, it will be removed from said network, including its alias '`db`'.

That differs from the old link ([docker 1.8 and before](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks)), which would [modify the `/etc/hosts`](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/#updating-the-etc-hosts-file) of the container who needed it. In that case, removing the linked container would not, indeed, change the `/etc/hosts`.
With the [new embedded docker-daemon DNS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/), there is no longer a need for that.

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318694/matt) suggests in the comments the following command and caveats:

> `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --force-recreate` otherwise the command never returns and the `db` container would never be removed.
>   `up` messes with stdout a bit though.
>   The exit status for the tests will be lost too, it's printed to screen instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this command is supposed to be a one-time running shell script. Can I just put `docker-compose.yml` next to my shell script and use `docker-compose run` instead of `docker run`?

Comment: Exactly. More precisely, it would be docker-compose up.

Comment: I'm guessing the PhpUnit component would require `run` so it's in the foreground and stdout appears.

Comment: Docker-compose should take care of both containers, doing the appropriate docker run behind the scene.

Comment: Maybe `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --force-recreate` otherwise the command never returns and the db container would never be removed.  `up` messes with stdout a bit though. The exit status for the tests will be lost too, it's printed to screen instead.

Comment: @matt good point. I will include that in the answer momentarily (I am on my phone right now)